# how to create react redux project to print content?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As i am a beginner i am not able to understand about react redux, i have a state
how can create a react redux project to display this state in table.

```
 this.state = {
      data: [{
        key: 1,
        name: 'Sumit',
        last_name: 'A',
      }, {
        key: 2,
        name: 'Roshan',
        last_name: 'S'
      }, {
        key: 3,
        name: 'Akash',
        last_name: 'Kumar'
      }, {
        key: 4,
        name: 'Om',
        last_name: 'Mehta'
      }],
    };
```

Comment: check this DOC example: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

Comment: I read the doc but i am not getting it properly how to display these data.Would you please help me..i am not getting how to display these state contents. @Mayank Shukla

Comment: @Mayank Shukla can you tel me how to define the state in redux? and how can i print those state data ?

Comment: sorry, don't have much idea about redux.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to install webpack, also you can install webpack-dev-server for testing purposes. Then you will need to install all necessary npm packages including `react-redux, react-router, babel`. You also need to have a reducer called `data` as every property of the state in Redux corresponds to reducer. It is really impossible to explain how to setup react-redux in a few words. I would adsvise you to go through the video tutorials for beginners by Dan Abramov (creator of Redux): https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: how can i define the state in the store?

Comment: I would recommend to read this: http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html

Comment: Can you please give me a simple example of store and displaying store contents?